# Triangle with integral side lengths and $\angle A=3\angle B$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, trigonometry, triangles

> $ABC$ is a triangle with integral side lengths. Given that $\angle A=3\angle B$, find the minimum possible perimeter of $ABC$.

I got this problem from an old book (which did not provide even a hint). I can think of some approaches, but all of them result in complicated Diophantine equations that would not be solvable without the help of a computer. Any suggestions?

Comment: @heron1000, what is the book's title, the author's name, the publisher's name, and the copyright date?  What was discussed in the book right before the question was asked?  This could provide a clue to what the author was thinking of when s/he made the question.

Answer (score 5):

Such triangles exist.  I found one 3:8:10, where the angle opposite 8 is 1/3 of that opposite 10.  The trick here is to pick really small primes in the form of $x+y\sqrt{-n}$, and cube the result.  Note here that we're using $n=7$, and the prime is $1\frac 12 + \frac 12\sqrt{-7}$.  This is a pretty tiny cube, one gets then a matrix

```
   ( 3  -7 )  (3)  (2)  (36)
   ( 1   3 )  (1)  (6)  (20)
               A         B = A^3
```

You then divide through by common factors, to get coordinates at $A =0,0$  $B=+6,0$, and $C=-9,5\sqrt{7}$.  The three sides are AB=6, AC=16, and BC=20, which gives the indicated triangle.

Comment: If $AB=6$, $BC=16$, and $CA=20$, then $\angle B\approx 124.2288663^\circ$, $\angle A\approx 41.40962211^\circ$, and $\angle C\approx 14.3615116^\circ$.  Thus, $\angle B=3\angle A$.  You might want to rename your sides so that $\angle A=3\angle B$.

Answer (score 1):

Giving it a try using elementary techniques.

In $\triangle ABC$, let $B=\theta$, $A=3\theta$, $C=\pi-4\theta$. By sine-rule
$$\frac{a}{\sin 3\theta}=\frac{b}{\sin \theta}=\frac{c}{\sin 4\theta}$$

so that $$a=b(3-4\sin^2\theta) \quad , \quad c=b(4\cos \theta \cos 2\theta)$$

On further simplification,
$$a=b(4\cos^2\theta-1) \quad , \quad c=b \cdot 4\cos \theta (2\cos^2 \theta-1)$$

$c>0$ places bound on $\cos \theta$ : $\cos \theta > 1/\sqrt{2} \Rightarrow \theta < 45^{\circ}$ which makes sense since $45^{\circ}+3\cdot 45^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$

We may choose any suitable value of $\cos \theta > 1/\sqrt{2} \approx 0.7071$.

Taking $\cos \theta = 3/4=0.75$, yields $a/b=5/4$, $c/b=3/8$. So one class of triangles would be multiples of
$$(a,b,c)=(10,8,3)$$

Taking $\cos \theta = 5/6$, yields $a/b=16/9$, $c/b=35/27$. So another class of triangles would be multiples of
$$(a,b,c)=(48,27,35)$$

and so on.